# Cant crack Responder hashes with John or Hashcat

Tags: password-cracking, hashcat, ntlm, john-the-ripper

I ran Responder in a test network and obtained hashes from a Windows machine. The logs for the machine show something like this (some bytes changed for security reasons) and are stored in a file called "SMB-NTLMv2-SSP-192.168.2.12.txt":

user::user-PC:1122334455667788:0340FB9C9E4F88BEEBBC92105213BD05:0101000000000000D5F72CCE1F6AD301265492A58DFAC6E50000000002000A005300411111111111111101000A0053004D0042003100320004000A002364171BCD43100320003000A0053004D0042003100320005000A0053004D004200310032000800300030000000000000000100000000200000AAD247A0EB2290A13305EA760905EEFD95C50BF057C3BAEEABC821111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000900160063006900660073002F006100730064006100730066000000000000000000

The options i used in Responder were -wF.

The problem is i cannot crack this hash at all. All guides show the attacker inputting the log file into hashcat or JohnTheRipper and the hash being cracked, but when I do it i get:

In John: "No password hashes loaded (see FAQ)"
In Hashcat: "No hashes loaded"

It seems both programs are unable to recognize the hash. Also, i'm confused: what does each field (separated by a semicolon) mean in the hash? I know it's a challenge-response protocol, so which part is the challenge and which one is the response?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Responder hash may be invalid, corrupt, or using an outdated format. Is it possible that you're using an older version of Responder, as noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41487203/hashcat-not-working-on-netntlmv2-hashes-obtained-by-responder)?

Showing my work:

Generally, the best way to validate your hashcat attack is correct for a specific hash type is to try your attack against an example hash from [the hashcat wiki list of example hashes](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes). For NetNTLMv2 (mode 5600 - is that what you're using?), here is the example hash for the string 'hashcat':

admin::N46iSNekpT:08ca45b7d7ea58ee:88dcbe4446168966a153a0064958dac6:5c7830315c7830310000000000000b45c67103d07d7b95acd12ffa11230e0000000052920b85f78d013c31cdb3b92f5d765c783030

... which my hashcat (4.0.1) loads fine for me with:

```
hashcat -m 5600 -a 3 test.hashes
```

But my version of hashcat fails to load your hash -- not with the "no hashes loaded" that you're seeing, but with a "salt-value exception" error. (Is it possible that you're running an older version of hashcat?)

I also tried a couple of the Responder hashes shown in some tutorial articles ([like this one](https://zone13.io/post/cracking-ntlmv2-responses-captured-using-responder/)), and I am able to load those into hashcat using -m 5600.

So I've tentatively concluded that there's something wrong with your hash.

Comment: Hey! 
I could get it to work. John doesn't support NTLM, i think, but Hashcat was only missing the "-m 5600" option. 
I think the "salt-value exception" you got is because i changed a few bytes of the hash in the question for security reasons.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah,I see - totally makes sense. Yes, if you don't supply a target algorithm with -m ("mode"), hashcat defaults to -m 0 (MD5). :)